# LibreOffice Writer dispalys Extra dash Underscore _ after each persian/arabic character!

Tags: libreoffice

I have similar problem in the LibreOffice (version 4.0.2.2). My Ubuntu is 13.04
If I type الآن in my libreoffice writer, It displays: اـلآــن‌ـ
LibreOffice displays a dash (UnderScore): _ after each Persian character and if I type some characters this dashes may change position or be reduced: 
ا       اـ 
ال     اـل‌ـ 
الآ     اـلآــ 
الآن   ا_لآــن‌ـ 
above I typed some samples of what I type what LibreOffice displays.
This problem Only occurs in LibreOffice Writer, Not in Calc, nor in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a function of the `CTL` setting which can be found in `Tools > Options > Language settings > Languages`.  Do you have the same problem if you set this value to, e.g., "Farsi"?

Comment: Yes, in Tools > Options > Language settings > Languages I set: Locale setting = Farsi <br/> CTL = Default-Farsi